# Show json data in table in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json result like this

```
{
    "discipline":"ACLS",
    "course": [
                    {
            "value":"ACLS Initial",
            "classes":"0",
            "students":"0"
        },
        {
            "BLS":"CPR Instructor Class",
            "classes":"0",
            "students":"0"
        }       
       ]    
}
```

and i need to show this list inside a table like this [image]
I know how to show data inside a table in Angular but this particular json set and its required design is confusing me. In other tables i have shown data like this

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                      <th>Date/Time</th>
                      <th>Course</th>
                      <th>Location</th>
                      <th>Instructor</th>
                      <th>Enrolled</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td class="trim">25/6/2019</td>
                  <td class="trim">Chemistry</td>
                  <td class="trim">Islamabad</td>
                  <td class="trim">Shaharyar</td>
                  <td class="trim">Yes</td>     
                  <td class="trim">
                    <nb-select>

                      <nb-option value="2">Edit</nb-option>
                      <nb-option value="3">Delete</nb-option>
                      <nb-option value="4">View</nb-option>
                    </nb-select>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Can you please tell me how i can show the above json in my table as shown in picture? 
P.S: i have just assumed that json will be like this i have not yet written code for the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different structure for your data than what you have posted in your OP.

You can instead create an array of objects for `disciplines` where each object will represent a `discipline`. Within each `discipline`, there can be multiple `courses` so add a `courses` key whose value will be an array of objects where each object will represent a `course`.

The new data structure for `disciplines` will look something like this

```js
[{
    "name": "ACLS",
    "courses": [{
        "name": "ACLS Initial",
        "classes": "0",
        "students": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "ACLS Renewal course",
        "classes": "0",
        "students": "0"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "BLS",
    "courses": [{
        "name": "CPR Instructor Class",
        "classes": "0",
        "students": "0"
    }]
}]
```

Now you just need to display the data in the UI using nested `ngFor`.

```html
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let discipline of disciplines">
        <tr>
            <td>{{discipline.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let course of discipline.courses">
            <td></td>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.classes}}</td>
            <td>{{course.students}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-ngfor-in-table).